# bind error 98, "Address already in use" after process restart

Tags: networking, bind

I am running custom service process at ubuntu 18.04.1, an face the following problem:
During debugging, I often stop the process and start it again, and when process tryes to bind a socket, it received error 98, and then it tryes again within 1 second interval, until bind() is succesfull. This issue can take up to couple of minutes, and during this period lsof does not show any processes bound to this port.

How can I avoid this behaviour?

Comment: use ps to check for the process after your stop it, it may still be running or the bind is still in affect and it takes 30 seconds for the process to stop and the bind to be released, when happens if you do a restart instead of stop?

Comment: I killed process fy GDB command, as it was debugged. ps does not show process running, and lsof also does not show if any processes are bound to the port and listening.

Comment: Also I have a graceful shutdown in a programm by SIGHUP, where I close all sockets before exit, but issue exists in this case too. 
Interesting thing - the possibility of this issue is about 40%, so in 40% cases I got an error when restarting process, and in 60% I do not see an error.